building a max heap from class Items
i am building a max heap with class item which has (name ,price ,category) one time by comparing the name and one time by comparing the price but there is a problem with the name comparing
here is the class item
class Item
{
    int Price;

public:
    Item(string name, string category, int price);
    string itemName;
    string Category;

    string get_category();
// operators to compare between prices
    bool operator<(Item &another);
    bool operator>(Item &another);
    bool operator<=(Item &another);
    bool operator>=(Item &another);
// operators to compare between names
    bool operator>(string &another);
    bool operator<(string &another);
    bool operator<=(string &another_name);
    bool operator>=(string &another_name);
    void print();
    bool operator==(Item &another);
};

and i have two functions, one to make the max heap by comparing prices which works fine
void Heap::Max_heapify(int size, int i)
{
    int left = 2*i+1;
    int right = 2*i+2;
    int Max = i;

    if (heap[Max] < heap[left] and left < size)
    {
        Max = left;
    }
    if (heap[Max] < heap[right] and right < size)
    {
        Max = right;
    }

    if (Max != i)
    {
        swap(heap[i], heap[Max]);
        Max_heapify(size, Max);
    }
void Heap::Build_Max()
{
    for (int i = (heap.size() / 2 - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Max_heapify(heap.size(), i);
    }
}

and another one to compare by names
void Heap::Max_heapify_By_Name(int size, int i)
{

    int left = 2*i+1;
    int right = 2*i+2;
    int Max = i;
    if ((heap[Max] < heap[left].itemName) and left <= size)
    {
        Max = left;
    }
    if ((heap[Max] < heap[right].itemName) and right <= size)
    {
        Max = right;
    }
    if (Max != i)
    {
        swap(heap[i], heap[Max]);
        Max_heapify_By_Name(size, Max);
    }
}
void Heap::Build_Max_By_Name()
{
    int n = heap.size();
    for (int i = floor(n / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        Max_heapify_By_Name(n, i);
    }
}


here is the class heap
class Heap
{
    vector<Item> heap;

public:
    Heap(vector<Item>);
    void insert_item(Item item);
    void Delete_item(int index);
    int Get_parent(int num);
    int Get_Left_Chlid(int num);
    int Get_Right_Child(int num);
    void Insert_Item(Item item);
    void Heap_sort();    
    void Heap_sort_Name();
    void Max_heapify(int size ,int i );
    void Min_heapify(int i);
    void Build_Max();
    void Build_Min();
    void Max_heapify_By_Name(int size,int i);
    void Min_heapify_By_Name(int i);
    void Build_Max_By_Name();
    void Build_Min_By_Name();
    void print_heap();
};

the problem is that when i try to call the build_Max_by_name i just don't get any output
here is the main.cpp
int main()
{
    Item i1("item1", "food", 123);
    Item i2("item5", "food", 120);
    Item i3("item4", "food", 156);
    Item i4("item6", "food", 1234);
    Item i5("item3", "food", 122);
    Item i6("item2", "food", 111);
    Item i7("item7", "food", 161);
    vector<Item> arr;
    //
    arr.push_back(i1);
    arr.push_back(i2);
    arr.push_back(i3);
    arr.push_back(i4);
    arr.push_back(i5);
    arr.push_back(i6);
    arr.push_back(i7);
    //
    Heap a(arr);
    //
    a.Build_Max_By_Name();
    a.print_heap();
    }

i thought that the problem was the overloaded operator but when i checked it was working fine
and here is its implementation
bool Item::operator<(Item &another)
{ 
// to compare prices
    return (this->Price < another.Price);
}
bool Item::operator<(string &another_name)
{
    return (this->itemName < another_name);
}

the max heap with price compare is working fine but the name one just doesn't give any output i'd appreciate the help.

This seems relevant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap

Item i1 ... Item I5 ... - Looks like you want to use a container rather than individual variables (std::vector?)..

i put the items in a vector called arr and then make the heap from it.

@ahmedmohsen You do realize that heap functions already exist in C++?

i know but its for a college assignment

"just doesn't give any output" -- Then force it to give some. Right before each call to Max_heapify_By_Name, add output std::cerr << "Calling Max_heapify_By_Name(" << size << ", " << Max <<)\n"; (and similarly with n and i).

Another thing you might want to do is compare your functions character-by-character to see where they differ. Can you justify each difference?

@ahmedmohsen and i have two functions, one to make the max heap by comparing prices which works fine -- Look at both of those functions.  They are virtually the same thing except for the comparison.  Instead of writing two functions, write one general function, and pass the comparison criteria as a parameter that you call.  Then if that function works for prices, it will be guaranteed to work for names.  You should have realized that you were doing a copy-paste of the same code, and once you saw that, you should have attempted to write a single function instead of duplicating code.

Also, the C++ heap functions that you were given a link to works just like that.  How do those functions get to figure out the sorting criteria "automatically"?  They work by allowing the user to pass the comparison criteria as a parameter, and the general heap function simply calls the user's comparison function.

@ahmedmohsen See this example.  This allows Build_Max to be written once, and the comparison is passed in as a parameter.  If there is any bug, you have only one "build max" function to debug instead of multiple ones, with the added benefit that if build_max works for one member, it will work for all.  I only changed Build_Max, but you could do similar changes to all the functions.

@PaulMcKenzie thanks i tried using the comparison as a parameter and made a single function and it works fine and i think it didn't work first because of the overloaded operator

There's this std::ranges::make_heap for that purpose. Don't reinvent the wheel; famous algorithms have standard entries: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/make_heap
